# Haskell IO (String) and String

Tags: haskell, input, io

I want to write functions and put result to string.

I want function:

```
read' :: FilePath -> String
```

I use:

```
:t readFile
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

I make:

```
read' :: IO ()
read' = do
     str <- readFile "/home/shk/workspace/src/test.txt" 
     putStrLn str
```

I want to ask str is string or not?

We know that:

```
:t putStrLn
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

Then why i can't:

```
read' :: String
read' = do
     str <- readFile "/home/shk/workspace/lxmpp/src/test.txt" 
     str
```

I get error that:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `IO String'
    In the return type of a call of `readFile'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        str <- readFile "/home/shk/workspace/lxmpp/src/test.txt"
    In the expression:
      do { str <- readFile "/home/shk/workspace/src/test.txt";
           str }
```

Thank you.

Comment: The readFile in the do-notation implies you are in the IO monad, and the IO monad cannot be escaped !

Comment: @is7s unless you use `unsafePerformIO`!

Comment: The first rule of unsafePerformIO is you don't tell anyone about unsafePerformIO!

Comment: @Thomas Uh oh, likes like Real World Haskell broke that rule

Comment: @Thomas Unless he understands generalized prepohistozygomorphisms

Comment: We really want abstract duplicates of questions, this should be a TFAQ, where T = 'too'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think no one has answered this, very important question, yet:

> I want to ask str is string or not?

I will try to.

The type of the variable `str` is `String`, yes.
However, the scope of this variable is very limited. I think desugaring the do-notation is necessary for understanding:

```
read' = readFile "/home/shk/workspace/src/test.txt" >>= (\str -> putStrLn str)
```

I think here it becomes more clear why `str` is not good enough. It is an *argument* of the function you pass to `>>=`. Its value only becomes available when someone calls your function, which happens only when the `IO` action containing it is being executed.

Also, the type of `read' :: IO ()` is determined not so much by the `putStrLn str`, but rather by the return type of the operator `>>=`. Have a look at it (specialized to the `IO` monad):

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

You can see that the result is always an `IO b` action, so trying to change any of arguments won't help.

You can read some monad tutorial if you want to understand why the type is the way it is. The intuition behind it is: you can't perform an action without performing an action.

And on the practical side of the question, to use the value returned by some action, instead of trying to do `use (extractValue inputAction)`, which does not make sense because `extractValue` is not possible, try `inputAction >>= use` if your `use` does involve I/O, or `fmap use inputAction` if it does not.

Answer (score 10):

Just to quibble a bit more, while the other answers are perfectly correct, I want to emphasize something: Something with the type `IO String` isn't just a string that the type system won't let you get at directly. It's a computation that *performs I/O to get a string for you*. Applying `readFile` to a file path doesn't return a `String` value any more than putting a steak next to a meat grinder magically turns them into a hamburger.

When you have some code like this:

```
foo = do let getStr = readFile "input.txt"
         s1 <- getStr
         s2 <- getStr
         -- etc.
```

That doesn't mean you're "taking the string out of `getStr` twice". It means you're performing the computation twice and can easily get different results between the two.

Comment: The great thing about magic hamburgers is that you can eat them without worrying about side-effects!

Answer (score 4):

You should use `return str` in `read'` if you want it to return `str` instead of `()`. You can't strip `IO` from the type of `read'`, since it's not a pure function. To get a better grip on how input/output in Haskell works I recommend you [to read a tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output).

Comment: While this is correct, note that there is no point in binding with `<-` just to immediately `return` it. You can just write `read' = readFile "/path/to/test.txt"`. This is the [second monad law](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Laws).

Answer (score 1):

As a more detailed reason why: It allows impurity.

You absolutely can not perform IO during a pure operation, or it would completely break referential transparency. Technically you can use `unsafePerformIO` but it would break referential transparency in this case - you should only use that if you can guarantee that the result is *always the same*.

Comment: Is the guarantee of result being the same enough to claim purity? I mean, can `unsafePerformIO (putStrLn "hello!")` be called pure?

Comment: @Rotsor: Don't forget that it has to be thread-safe as well. Guaranteeing purity manually is difficult!

Comment: @camccann I'm not sure how to interpret your comment. Are you extending the notion of purity the monadic user defined, or suggesting the practical difficulties of achieving it? If not extended, it can be achieved by, say, `safePerformIO = unsafePerformIO :: IO () -> ()`, right? Which is bad... Or not?

Comment: @Rotsor: Ah, sorry for lack of clarity. I was answering your questions with "no, that's not enough" and adding an additional requirement for something to be pure, namely that even if all it uses is `ST`-style contained impurity, it must also be independent of possible concurrent access to resources. Ensuring purity in the presence of `unsafePerformIO` is very, very difficult indeed.

Comment: @Rotsor I would consider the printing to the screen as being a result of the function. But yes, thats generally a sign that its not pure ^_^. Basically, you shouldn't care whether or not the previous value calculated is used.