# Managing the IO monad 

Tags: haskell

I'm working on learning some Haskell (please excuse the newbie error)-

This routine errors out. My understanding of the do & <- syntax is that they extract the non-Monad type from the monad. So that understanding is flawed: what's the correct understanding here?

```
exister :: String -> Bool
exister path = do
  fileexist <- doesFileExist path 
  direxist <- doesDirectoryExist path
  return fileexist || direxist
```

error

```
ghc -o joiner joiner.hs

joiner.hs:53:2:
    Couldn't match expected type `Bool' against inferred type `m Bool'
    In the first argument of `(||)', namely `return fileexist'
    In the expression: return fileexist || direxist
    In the expression:
        do { fileexist <- doesFileExist path;
             direxist <- doesDirectoryExist path;
               return fileexist || direxist }
```

Comment: [You cannot escape the IO monad](http://spl.smugmug.com/Humor/Lambdacats/13227630_eKt46/5/1288212148_5KLHJ3V#960526421_MnNqB).

Comment: Judging by your comment below, you may want to check out this question and its answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628748/haskell-io-string-and-string (we really need a proper FAQ for this)

Comment: I think it may be helpful to point out that Haskell's `return` is not much like "return" in most languages. If you want a function that takes a number n, and "returns" n+1, you write `f n = n + 1`, not `f n = return n+1`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First problem: The line `return fileexist || direxist` is parsed as `(return fileexist) || direxist`, and you can’t pass `m Bool` as the first argument of `||`. Change it to `return (fileexist || direxist)`.

Second problem: You claim the return type of `exister` is `Bool`, but the compiler infers that it must be `IO Bool`. Fix it. (The `do` and `<-` syntax let you extract the `a` value from an `m a` value, but only if you promise to return an `m a` value.)

Comment: I assure you, I want exister to return a Bool, not a IO Bool.

Comment: @Paul: That's not possible. Whether a file/directory exists or not, depends on the environment. It is an impure function, and therefore it must return `IO Bool`. A pure function must always return the same output given the same input. That's clearly not the case here.

Comment: @hammar: so if my whole program is oriented around sucking data from the hard disk/network, munging it, and sending it out, I have to dork with the IO monad in all my computations?

Comment: @Paul Your computations can be pure, but your operation is clearly IO.  For example, a `main` routine that lives in the IO monad can get data from disk or network (ex: `x <- getData`) and pass that data to a pure computation (ex: `let result = computationOn x`) then send the result out (`sendOnNetwork result`).

Comment: @Thomas: hmm, I can feel that learning curve coming up. :) Thanks.

Comment: @Paul Nathan, I ran into your exact issues when I was starting. Fortunately, the learning curve is worth the work.

Answer (score 5):

The type you've given `exister :: String -> Bool` is for a function that returns an ordinary, non-monadic `Bool`. The actions you're performing, `doesFileExist path` and `doesDirectoryExist path` have type IO Bool, so the `m Bool` in the error message really means `IO Bool`. If you change the type of `exister` to return `IO Bool` instead, the type will be what you intend.

Also, in the last line, you need some more parens: `return (fileexist || direxist)`.