# How to evaluate IO Bools in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to write a function that takes an IO Bool and does stuff based on what this is, but I can't figure out how to evaluate the IO Bool. I tried saying `do cond` and `do {cond==True}` but got the error `Couldn't match expected type 'Bool' against inferred type 'a b'`. Can someone direct me to a solution?

Comment: As someone mentioned not long ago, we should probably have one or two FAQs on the `haskell` tag wiki about IO. This question, or one of these might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904169/managing-the-io-monad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628748/haskell-io-string-and-string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to unpack/pull the bool out of IO before you can use it.  Here's an example:

```
main = useBool trueIO

trueIO :: IO Bool
trueIO = return True

useBool :: IO Bool -> IO ()
useBool a = do
    b <- a
    putStrLn (show b)
```