# How to put function into module?

Tags: haskell, module, program-entry-point

I've got the function:

```
isSortedUp x y z = if x>y && y>z then True else False
```

and I want to put it into module UP.

This function I want to put into module down:

```
isSortedDown x y z = if x<y && y<z then True else False
```

And then call them in the main program:

```
import System.Environment
import Up
import Down
main = do
  args<-getArgs
  let a = args !! 0
  let b = args !! 1
  let c = args !! 2
  if (isSortedUp a b c) || (isSortedDown a b c) then return (True) else return(False)
```

How to put and call this functions?

New code
Main.hs

```
import System.Environment
import Up
import Down  
main = do
  args<-getArgs
  let a = args !! 0
  let b = args !! 1
  let c = args !! 2
  if (isSortedUp a b c) || (isSortedDown a b c) then return(True) else return(False)
```

Up.hs

```
module Up (isSortedUp) where
isSortedUp x y z = if x>y && y>z then return(True) else return(False)
```

Down.hs

```
module Down (isSortedDown) where
isSortedDown x y z = if x<y && y<z then return(True) else return(False)
```

Comment: Just as a minor critique: don't write `if P then True else False`, just write `P`.  Likewise in the monad: `if P then return True else return False` is simpler as just `return P`.  Finally, note that `isSortedDown a b c = isSortedUp c b a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules in Haskell are broken up by file.  So to put `isSortedDown` in it's own module `Down`, you'd create a new file `Down.hs` and drop it's contents inside with the `module` declaration:

```
module Down (isSortedDown) where

isSortedDown x y z = if x<y && y<z then True else False
```

Then, providing your `Main` module has access to this module (in the same directory, for instance), it should import and be accessible.

For more information on modules in Haskell, read:

- http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/modules.html
- http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules (Specifically the "Making your
  own modules" section -- near the bottom)

Comment: I've got `could not find module 'Down'` but task1.hs is in the same directory as Down.hi and Up.hi

Comment: Since you clicked the checkmark, that indicates that this question has already been answered. If you're still having trouble, you might want to ask on the #haskell IRC channel, or possibly create a new SO question.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: the module `Foo` should be in `Foo.hs`.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: What command are you using to compile this?  Also (for this simple case), you need to be sure you run this command from same directory as your Haskell source files.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: it looks like you are compiling from a different directory than the source files.  So if your main module is called `task1.hs`, and you are "in" the same directory as `task.hs`, you should be able to compile with `ghc --make task1.hs`.  Just as long as Down.hs is in the same directory as well, it should all compile fine.

Comment: I've copied all files of this task(I've renamed task to Main -so files are - Down.hs Up.hs Main.hs) to directory where ghc.exe. During the compilation error occured - `couldn't match expected type 'Bool' with actual type 'm0 Bool'

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов: Good, that import of Up and Down are working then.  I'd say go ahead and accept this answer for the import portion, then open a new question with this new error.  Without getting too much into it, it looks like this question/answer may help you with that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618092/how-to-evaluate-io-bools-in-haskell/7618154#7618154

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can write simply:

```
isSortedDown x y z = x<y && y<z
```